# Using $.when() with a variable array of functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to use when() to control finishing of multiple AJAX calls such as:

```
$.when(
    $.ajax( "test.aspx" ),
    $.ajax( "test2.aspx" ),
    ...
).then(...);
```

Finally I would like to use $.when with results of function calls **from a variable array**. I don't realize how.

How can we correct the next construction? The problem it's incorrect because we pass an array of Function objects, but not results of function calls.

```
funcArray = [ 
    function() { return $.ajax( "test.aspx" ) }, 
    function() { return $.ajax( "test2.aspx" ) }
]

if( cond )
{
    funcArray.push( function() { return $.ajax( "test3.aspx" ) } )
}

$.when.apply( null, funcArray ).then(...); // how to correct here and probably somewhere else?
```

Comment: Your functions have to return the result of `$.ajax()`: `function() { return $.ajax( "test.aspx" ) }`

Comment: @ComFreek I suppose it's a good correction but it's not the solution, isn't it?

Comment: `$.when` accepts promises as its arguments, not *functions returning promises*. You'll first need to call all your functions, store the returned promises in an array and pass *that* array to `$.when` (using `apply`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mattias Buelens already said in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21353131/using-when-with-a-variable-array-of-functions/21353231#comment32195173_21353131), the problem is that you pass functions returning promises to `$.when` – not the actual promises.

You have to iterate the array and return the result of each function call.

There are several ways to do so:

- **[Most stable]** Using jQuery's [$.map](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) function:

  ```
  $.when.apply(null, $.map(funcArray, function (val) {
      return val();
    })
  );
  ```
- Using [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

  ```
  $.when.apply(null, funcArray.map(function (val) {
      return val();
    })
  );
  ```
- Firefox ≥ 22 also allows a so-called syntax of [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/arrow_functions):

  ```
  $.when.apply(null, funcArray.map(fun => fun()));
  ```

Comment: If compatibility is an issue, you can also use [`$.map(array, func)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) to replace `array.map(func)`.